# What is the best way to print a Gtk.Widget to the printer?

Tags: printing, mono, gtk

I have a couple of (mostly) text widgets that I would like to render to a printer through a standard "Print..." menu option. One widget is a Mono.TextEditor document, and the other is a Gtk.TextView.

I'm looking for a pretty basic print for now, which might wrap long lines, and add page numbers. Do I need to code all of this myself somehow?

If you have pointers, that would be great, especially if they were in C#.

Comment: Did you print widget? What functions did you use for it?

Comment: I had to manually print the text. See:  https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/src/master/Source/Calico/Printing.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For line wrap and justification, one can use pango Layout
options, as described for Python at [pygtk/class-pangolayout](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-pangolayout.html) or for C at [pango/pango-Layout-Objects](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/pango/pango-Layout-Objects.html).  See functions pango_layout_set_wrap() and  pango_layout_set_justify().

Also see the example-code routines begin_print, do_page_setup, and do_print in file pygtk-demo/demos/print_editor.py, if you have installed pygtk on your system.  (On my system, the full path to directory of Python Gtk demo files currently is /usr/share/doc/pygtk2-2.17.0/examples/pygtk-demo/demos)

For printer setup dialog, see [gtk-High-level-Printing-API](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-High-level-Printing-API.html) for C, or [class-gtkprintoperation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkprintoperation.html) for Python.